# Como lidar com os valores nulos de um vetor, na conversão de String para Double?

Tags: java, array, lista, conversão-de-tipo

Preciso exibir as 10 maiores clausulas de rescisão de contrato, que estão em um vetor, extraídos de um arquivo CSV. Aqui, quando me refiro a clausulas de rescisão de contrato, quero dizer valores monetários(dinheiro), mais precisamente para multa de rescisão de contrato.

O que pensei em fazer?

1. Converter a coluna com os valores das clausulas de `String` para o
   tipo `Double`, pois existem valores muito altos;
2. Ordenar do maior para o menor;
3. Converter de volta para String; e
4. Adicionar em um `List<String>`, pois é o que preciso retornar no método que estou usando.

O problema acontece quando tento converter de `String` para `Double`, pois nessa coluna **existem diversas pessoas sem um valor de clausula de rescisão definido**, ou seja, seus valores estão em branco, o que entendo como nulo.

Se uso tipo primitivo `double`, ele retorna uma exceção dizendo que não é possível converter uma `String` em `double`. Se uso `Double`, a exceção diz que a String está vazia.

O que posso fazer para contornar esse problema?

Trechos dos códigos que estou usando:

Para fazer a leitura do arquivo CSV:

```
static String[] jogadores;
static Double[] rescisao = new Double[17995];

public static BufferedReader lendoCSV(String arquivo, String separador) {
        BufferedReader conteudoArquivo = null;
        String linha = "";
        boolean cabecalhoLido = false;
        int i = 0;

        try{
            conteudoArquivo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(arquivo));
            while((linha = conteudoArquivo.readLine()) != null) {
                if(!cabecalhoLido) {
                    cabecalhoLido = true;
                    continue;
                } i++;

                jogadores = linha.split(separador);
                idade[i] = Integer.parseInt(jogadores[6]);
                nomeCompleto[i] = jogadores[2];
                nacionalidade[i] = jogadores[14];
                nomeDosClubes[i] = jogadores[3];
                rescisao[i] = Double.parseDouble(jogadores[18]);
            } 
            System.out.println("A leitura do arquivo deu certo!");
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Arquivo não encontrado: \n" + e.getMessage());
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e ) {
            System.out.println("Indice fora dos limites: \n" + e.getMessage());
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro de entrada de dados: \n" + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if(conteudoArquivo != null) {
                try {
                    conteudoArquivo.close();
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Erro de entrada de dados: \n" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        return conteudoArquivo;
    }
```

Quando tento converter para `Double`, pois tentei usar `double` primitivo, recebo essa exceção:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:      Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to String

Se tento usar `Double`:

```
static Double[] rescisao = new Double[17995];
```

Recebo essa exceção:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty
>   String    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown
>   Source)   at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)  at
>   challenge.Main.lendoCSV(Main.java:46)     at
>   challenge.Main.main(Main.java:171)

Método que estou usando e que precisa retornar uma `List`:

```
public static List<String> maioresClausulasDeRescisao() {
    List<String> clausulas = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        clausulas.add(rescisao[i]);
        System.out.println(clausulas);
    }
    return clausulas;
}
```

Comment: Antes até de ver esse erro tem outro mais grave: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101. `Double` aceita nulo sim. `double` que não aceita. No que foi apresentado não parece haver problemas, o erro deve estar em outra parte.

Comment: Precisa de mostrar também o resto do código associado a conversão.  `jogadores` é um `String[]` ? Qual o valor que está em `jogadores[18]` ? Qual o tipo de `rescisao` ?

Comment: Ok, @Maniero e @Isac! Obrigada! Vou complementar a pergunta! ^_^

Comment: Fiz correções na pergunta. :-)

Comment: Que eu saiba double e float nunca foram tipos pra ser usado em valor monetario.

Comment: @Articuno que tipo usar, então?

Comment: BigDecimal é geralmente usado para tipos monetarios.

Comment: @Articuno vou tentar.

Comment: @Articuno, eu tentei, mas o problema ainda são os valores em branco.

Answer (score 0):

O problema deve ocorrer por que tu estás tentando construir um objeto Double a partir de uma String vazia. O que faz lançar java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String, se fosse uma String nula também ocorreria erro, mas seria uma NullPointerException. Tu não podes passar para o método parseDouble(String s), ou para o construtor da classe Double uma String vazia ou nula.
Uma solução é testar o valor antes de construir o objeto. Tu podes usar try/catch e caso a variável do array de onde tu estás lendo os valores seja nula ou vazia, tu define um valor default para construir o teu objeto Double e dar prosseguimento ao programa sem erros. Segue abaixo um exemplo.

```
    String[] valores = new String[10];
    valores[1] = ""; // teste com null tbm
    Double rescisao;
    try {
        rescisao = Double.valueOf(valores[1]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        rescisao = 0.0;
    }

    System.out.println("Rescisao: " + rescisao);
```

Obs: Pode substituir Double por BigDecimal.